# extract contours based on percentiles from QGIS heatmap

Tags: qgis, heat-map, kernel-density

[image]

I have created a heatmap/kernal density estimation in QGIS. I now want to extract contours for the 75th and 90th percentile.

How would I go about doing this?

I have attached an image of what my KDE looks like at the moment. The plan is to extract contours for the 75th and 90th percentile so that I can then generate pseudo absences inside the contours.